# Does send() with MSG_MORE override TCP_NODELAY?

Tags: sockets, tcp

The `send(2)` man page states:

> MSG_MORE (since Linux 2.4.4)
>                 The  caller  has  more data to send.  This flag is used with TCP
>                 sockets to obtain the same effect as the TCP_CORK socket  option
>                 (see tcp(7)), with the difference that this flag can be set on a
>                 per-call basis.

And the `tcp(7)` man page states about `TCP_NODELAY`:

> This option is overridden by TCP_CORK;
>                 however, setting this option forces an explicit flush of pending
>                 output, even if TCP_CORK is currently set.

Does this mean that if I send using `MSG_MORE`, it overrides `TCP_NODELAY`?